# 'unknown option -W' error when running mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a backup of a database.

```
mysqldump -u ost-v1-11-x -xWt1z0*8 ost-v1-11-x_ > /master-db/ost-v1-11-x__.sql
```

But this results in an error:

```
mysqldump: unknown option '-W'
```

I have verified all of the paths / names / password.

I can use the same code to successfully backup another database on the same server and within the same user account.

I have tried Googling the '-W' error to no avail.

Comment: Is the server running on Windows?

Comment: ‪CentOS Linux 7.6.1810 (Core)‬ / 5.5.59-MariaDB-38.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you prefix a flag with a single `-`, it's called a *clustered option*. Each letter following the `-` is interpreted as a flag.

This is how you can use UNIX/Linux commands like:

```
ls -lar
```

This means the same thing as:

```
ls -l -a -r
```

So when you used this flag argument:

```
-xWt1z0*8
```

It assumed you mean you were using a cluster of options:

```
-x -W -t -1 -z -0 -* -8
```

The `-x` option is recognized by mysqldump. It's a short alias for `--lock-all-tables`.

Then the program proceeded to the next option you gave: `-W`. On Windows, this is a short alias for the `--pipe` option, but on UNIX/Linux/Mac, the option is not recognized.

I'm not sure what you intended by the option `-xWt1z0*8` but I would guess that's supposed to be a password. If so, you should use the `-p` flag, followed by your password.

```
mysqldump -u ost-v1-11-x -pxWt1z0*8 ...
```

Here's where mysqldump does something that breaks the conventions for clustered options. The `-p` option is prefixed with a single `-`, and yet the letters that follow it are *not* also interpreted as options. They're interpreted as the password.

If you want to make your usage more clear, stop using short options. Use only long option format:

```
mysqldump --user=ost-v1-11-x --password=xWt1z0*8 ...
```